# Make zmqpp::socket::connect a std::future

Tags: c++, c++11, zeromq, stdbind, std-future

I want to bind an overloaded function to make an `std::future`
`zmqpp::socket::connect` is created like that:

```
void    connect (endpoint_t const &endpoint)
```

The first thing i did was that:
`auto binded_connect = std::bind(&zmqpp::socket::connect, socket, endpoint);`

But that was bad because `zmqpp::socket::connect` is an overloaded function.
So I casted the connect function.

```
auto binded_connect = std::bind(static_cast<void(zmqpp::socket::*)(zmqpp::endpoint_t const&)>(&zmqpp::socket::connect), socket, endpoint);
```

The thing is g++ don't like that.
He says a lot of things about tuple but i think the most important is :

```
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:467:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::tuple<zmqpp::socket, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::tuple(zmqpp::socket&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’
```

So I don't really know what to do right now, I have no ideas where search to find answer.
I'm also sorry for bad english, not main language.
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `connect` is member method of `socket` class you need to pass `socket` object by pointer or reference:

> when invoking a pointer to non-static member function or pointer to non-static data member, the first argument has to be a reference or pointer to an object whose member will be accessed:   -> [more here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

```
auto binded_connect = std::bind(static_cast<void(zmqpp::socket::*)(zmqpp::endpoint_t const&)>(&zmqpp::socket::connect), 
       &socket, endpoint);
       ^^^^^^^^
or
auto binded_connect = std::bind(static_cast<void(zmqpp::socket::*)(zmqpp::endpoint_t const&)>(&zmqpp::socket::connect), 
       std::ref(socket), endpoint);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```